# Where are all the Malaysians at?

Tags: discussion, community, demographics

How many Stack Overflow users live and work in Malaysia?

I'm struggling to find a community of developers that I can meet on a regular basis to talk about programming, programming related issues, concerns, techniques, etc.

Does anyone know of some that already exist or would be interested in starting one?

Comment: Where in Malaysia?

Comment: you mean they're not in malaysia?

Comment: This seems to be a 'chat' type post. Perhaps can consider moving to chat? eg https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of the StackOverflow users:

If you cannot find anyone to meet in 3d, remember that we'll still be here. We're ready for nerd-talk any time. Our Malay sucks, but we make up for that by being plentiful.

Good luck with your quest.

Terima kasih sama-samaaa

Comment: is there a place where we can TALK instead of just ask and answer questions? :D

Comment: There are several irc channels dedicated to the SO community.  Search meta for them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Malaysian and I live and work in Malaysia.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing [January 5th](http://mysql.meetup.com/298/)?