# How can I move a discussion to chat before being prompted?

Tags: support, chat

I posted an answer to a question, and a user posted a comment that I feel is better handled in chat.  In a previous question, I was prompted to move the comment to chat when it went over a certain limit.  Can I move comments to chat without having hit that limit?

Comment: spam a bit. it will show you your link

Comment: @genesis, are you suggesting that I add a bunch of nonsense comments in order for the link to come up?

Comment: But be sure to clean up the spam afterward....

Comment: @MicahHainline: it was a joke. But to be honest, yes, but delete them afterwards

Comment: Or you could just post a comment saying "@user Can we discuss this in chat? link_to_chat_room_you_created"

Comment: I tried that solution @genesis, and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I'd turn that into a feature-request.

Comment: The feature-request: [Request the ability to move to chat before it is suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114578/135505).

Comment: Holy crap, for some reason, sometimes I can't seem to get prompted. I just tried it, but after 12 posts ... still nothing! any idea how to force this? does the content of the comments have to contain many characters? Does the other party have to respond often too?

Comment: @BenPhilipp It may be a requirement that there actually be a two-way discussion. I didn't see the link on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258401/what-is-up-with-all-the-printer-support-number-posts) until the last comment I made to Oded. I am guessing there has to be a minimum number of discussion comments going on before it prompts, as sometimes I see it immediately, sometimes not so much.

Comment: @EBrown Yes, that's what I have found too. It's a shame we have to guess towards that, this site does everything else so well

Comment: After trying to get OP into a chat I learned today that they need at least a rep of 20 to participate in chat.  I tried.

Comment: Pretty suboptimal state of affairs.  I they really want to stop chat in the comments this should be made easier.

Comment: I think you can bypass the 20 rep limit, by giving the users with less than <20 reps you want to chat a write access to your chatroom.

Comment: Related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps

Comment: @genesis Why not solve the problem (adding a new button or something) instead of asking millions of users to apply crooked workarounds?

Answer (score 17):

There are a few options to move comments to chat. You can create your own chat room and manually invite the other user to chat. You can also add a few extra messages to the conversation in the comments so that the option to move the conversation to chat comes up. You can then delete the extra messages and possibly tell the other user what you were doing. One last option is very cool, but can only be done by a moderator on the site where the conversation is taking place. All that you have to do is this command into the Javascript console:

```
$.post('admin/posts/' + post_id + '/move-comments-to-chat', {fkey:StackExchange.options.user.fkey});
```

where `post_id` is the id of the post with the comments you want to move to chat (obviously). This will leave a comment inviting the other user to chat, but the messages will still have to be manually deleted, which is easy if you are a moderator.

---

<sup>This is a bot run by @michaelpri a moderator on two SE sites</sup>

Comment: The javascript code doesn't work for me.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I am a moderator on a site. It has been a while, but I believe I tried it on the site that I moderate and it didn't work. Either way, mods now have a menu option to move everything to chat before the limit is reached.

Comment: The 2nd option (available to (almost) everyone and that doesn't involve creating a chat room), seems more like a lame workaround (*gainarie*) :) .

Comment: spamming does not work.

Comment: I just tried adding comments to get the "move to chat" to come up and after 8 additional comments I gave up and deleted the garbage I created

Answer (score -1):

[agf's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted#comment273454_106467) is correct.  Move the discussion to chat *by discussing in chat*, and stop commenting on the post.  If the other user doesn't want to move, that's OK, you don't **have** to discuss it. Flag one of the comments for moderator cleanup if need be, and move on :)

Comment: I'm interested in how the feature actually works.  It's more of a how-to question than a why-should.  If the answer is "It's impossible to move a small set of comments to chat" that's fine.  That's what I'm interested to know though.

Comment: @MicahHainline I can't find anything about the specifics of how it works, oddly, but there is no way to do it before it prompts you.

Comment: be aware that you can **create your own room** to have a discussion.

Comment: @studiohack But then the previous comments dont get migrated to the room like they would with the generated link.

Comment: Also when you have the option to automatically move the discussion to chat, you will have a generated link back to the origin at the beginning of the chat. It is much more work to do this manually by first having to create a new chat thread, then add a link to the original comments, and then create a link to the chat from the original comments.
Yes, it is a posible workaround, but it would be much better to have the option to do it in one click - Maybe as a link button on the right side of the comment field above the help link button saying "move to chat".

Comment: @awe How about a Greasemonkey script before StackExchange rolls out such functionality?