# Request the ability to move to chat before it is suggested

Tags: feature-request, information-display

Similar to [How can I move a discussion to chat before being prompted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted) but as an actual feature request. I'd like the ability to request a discussion move to chat before I'm suggested.

The reason for this, in some cases, is that I can guess that the direction of the comments are going to result in discussion. As a good citizen of SE sites, I feel like I know when it is appropriate and not appropriate. I'm not asking that I can suggest for other people to take it to a chat. Only for myself.

As an added bonus, I'd also like to make sure that any user (regardless of reputation) that is invited to chat can join the created room.

Use cases:

- Getting further information about the question. (E.g. author said I was wrong, but I don't want to water down the answer with figuring out why.)
- Helping the author with further, localized or specific, information or guidance that cannot, and should not, be discussed in the answer or posted within the question.

*Edit:* Here's some real world examples.

- I believe the answer incorrect, so I downvote and post a comment. The downvote and disagreement turn into a discussion. Whether or not I am wrong is not the issue here. It's the fact that I know it is going to turn into a discussion before hand. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362786/191837
- User doesn't totally understand the answer and needs further clarification. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8362917/191837

Comment: I've had new users say they can't open the chat due to reputation restrictions.

Comment: All you need to do is add a comment saying "Lets take this to chat", this hardly needs a specific "feature".

Comment: @meagar yes, but then you cannot bring over all the previous comments easily

Comment: @TLP Does that include the use of the current "let's take this to chat" feature? I'd say that this addition to the feature should only be available to people able to chat via reputation allowance.

Comment: @meagar This is an improvement on the existing feature (that moves all comments, etc) to chat after it appears it has devolved into discussion. The biggest reason for this addition from my point of view is to beat the SO trigger to the punch when I, as an experienced resident, know that the trigger will happen anyway.

Comment: @KevinPeno Both. Like you, I suggested taking it to chat before the prompt. Might be that the user didn't try again. Personally I see no reason why low rep users should not be allowed to be *invited* to a private chat.

Comment: @TLP I'd agree. I think the chat limitation should only include joining public rooms and creating new ones. Invitations should trump this requirement.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree that both are very similar in nature. Should I edit the linked one to add my use cases and what not to the single use case provided there? I just need to know the best course of action without losing my additions to the suggestion.

Comment: @KevinPeno: I think it may be better to add an answer to that one with a link to here. Like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107411/135505) from Nicol Bolas.