# Insert a "Let us continue this discussion in chat" comment before thread gets messy

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

I've seen [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106467/how-can-i-move-a-discussion-to-chat-before-being-prompted), but there seem to be no proper solution.

I suggest an ability to insert a "Let us continue this discussion in chat" comment before the thread gets messy enough to fit the requirement. The point is to prevent the problem before it occurs.

Perhaps this should become a privilege for users of X reputation or more?

Your opinions on the subject?

Comment: I'd rather it be a privilege for users of X reputation or more to turn off chat and these comments altogether. Since I can't do that, I generally use the appearance of the prompt as an indication that I've spent more than enough time trying to help the user and am justified in giving up.

Comment: @CodyGray I have turned off this feature, see [Add a confirmation before moving comments to a chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121954/add-a-confirmation-before-moving-comments-to-a-chat/123271#123271).

Comment: @Rob: Thanks, that's very useful...even if I wasted about 30 minutes reading the Chrome documentation trying to figure out how to create and install my own userscript. I guess just because I'm a programmer doesn't mean I know about all types of programming; how embarrassing. Anyway, now I wonder if it's really a good idea. Now how do I know when I've spent too long trying to be helpful and when to give up?

Comment: @CodyGray When you get the feeling: "Ugh, (s)he doesn't show any efforts in trying to understand me" or "Pfft, I can't be bothered any more." Installing the script is not hard. The easiest way to do that is by storing the code in a `.user.js` file, and opening it in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't want such feature here.

Why? Because I think it will cause lots of comments to be "lost" and become private.

Questions and answers are public - anyone can see them. Comments are related bits of information that should also be public.

If someone want to discuss things in private, he/she can always create new chat room and invite the other person (in a comment) to join the room - can't see any reason to have such thing always available.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119011/how-should-long-comment-threads-with-important-information-in-them-be-handled

Comment: Changing the link automatically after a few days to the transcript would cure that, no? Those rooms _are_ public.

Comment: @Tim what do you mean "changing the link"? Anyway the rooms are public, but people won't go and search the list of chat rooms just to see comments. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. I don't know why everyone's so eager to get rid of comments. If the comment discussion is potentially useful, it *should* be available for everyone to read. I've learned at least as much by reading comments as I have from reading answers. Obviously that doesn't mean *all* comment threads are useful, and there are a lot of pointless or obsolete comments that should be removed. I delete my own and flag others' for deletion; I would encourage everyone to do the same. But trying to eliminate comments altogether is the **wrong** idea. And pushing them to chat is worse.

Comment: @CodyGray and ShadowWizard: Can you explain this?  My understanding was that using the move-discussion-to-chat feature *preserves* the discussion and association with the post.

Comment: @feetwet the link to chat is not preserved, or at least can be easily deleted, I just checked and as you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246432/how-to-pass-im-not-a-robot), there is no comment telling the discussion moved to [this chat room](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/816/2015/1/1). In this specific case it was by mistake and the chat does not contain any extra contents, but usually there might be useful things in there that are not visible under the relevant post itself.

Comment: So it sounds like you don't object to the feature per se, but rather the feature if implemented *before* addressing the disappearing-chat-discussion defect?  (Or disappearing-chat-discussion "feature," if you are so inclined.)

Comment: @feetwet not totally correct. Even with a link, it will still be hard to follow. I don't have a problem with the current mechanism that cause only long comment threads to be moved, just with making it always available.