# How to pass "I'm not a robot"

Tags: support, captcha

I didn't have trouble answering questions in the past, but now I fail the human verification check.

Basically, instead of a CAPTCHA, I can check "I'm not a robot". When I check it, it goes away and I get a spinning circle animation.

I don't seem to be able to do anything afterwards; I waited a few minutes, nothing further happened.

I tried with Firefox and Chrome, with and without my ISP's proxy, but it's all the same.

So, how does one pass the human verification stage? I am pretty sure I am not a robot, but am unable to convince Stack Exchange of that.

Comment: Sounds like CDN is blocked on your side, so required JavaScript files fails to load. In Chrome, click F12, go to Network tab, reload, and you'll see what exactly is being blocked. Either some firewall/proxy or your ISP is the culprit.

Comment: Anything specifically to watch out for (like a hostname)? Chrome doesn'T seem to report anything as blocked. In firefox I use noscript to block google-analytics, but even completely disabling noscript doesn't help.

Comment: Sort the Network tab by status and hard-refresh (CTRL+F5), do you see anything which is not 200?

Comment: Also, here on MSE it doesn't work with CDN, do this on a site where you suffer from the problem you described.

Comment: I get lots of 200s, one 101, and, after checkmarking the captcha checkbox, two https requests to google that seemingly hang (no reply).

Comment: So those last two requests are most likely the problem... what is the URL of both?

Comment: I can't seem to select it or copy it, and its too long tot ype in. They start with https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/frame?c=.... There are other requests to https://www.google.com/js/... that succeed, so I don't think there is any filtering (especially not of TLS).

Comment: Right click the line and choose "Open link in new tab", then you can copy the URL from the address bar. :)

Comment: First thing I tried, but right click doesn't open a popup.

Comment: hmm.... no further ideas, sorry, but looks like it's something on your side otherwise we would be getting tons of reports.

Comment: Thanks for your help - "but looks like it's something on your side" it only affects stackexchange, and only since it uses the new captcha, but anyway, since stackexchange now blocks me, no answers from me anymore it seems.

Comment: Can you try from a different computer? Maybe even different ISP e.g. friend's computer? I can understand if it's too much to ask, just trying to help you point the exact issue, which most likely can't be resolved by Stack Exchange anyway.

Comment: Yeah, this post is *exactly* what a robot would say. Nice try.

Comment: A few things I wanted to add - first, Jaydles insinuating that I am dishonest is really evil, shame on you. Second, this question recently earned me the "popular question" tag, which is evidence that maybe the problem isn't so rare after all. And lastly, the occurance of this has been greatly reduced recently, so I can comment/answer again, at least at the moment.

Comment: I definitely don't think that Jaydles is saying that you're being dishonest - I think it's more like "It's the dumb captcha's fault, nice try with making a working Captcha, Google".

Comment: I hit this problem and looked in the Javascript Console in Chrome's element inspector (F12).  This showed that required resources were being blocked – which prompted me to disable my ad blocker.  Once I'd done this, the page loaded as expected.

Answer (score 4):

If you are having problems with getting past the "I'm not a robot" Captcha, make sure that your JavaScript is enabled. I had to go into the network to enable mine last night to fix a similar problem viewing my gift cards, as Captcha was needed to view them.

Answer (score 3):

1. On the page where you’ve encountered “I’m not a robot” Recaptcha, look at the element’s code.
2. Find a link that begins with `www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor`.
3. Copy the "k" parameter from that link (after “k=”).
4. Send a GET-request in this form:
   `http://2captcha.com/in.php?key=YOUR_CAPTCHA_KEY&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=%googlekey%`
   where
   where `YOUR_CAPTCHA_KEY` is your key from `https://2captcha.com/setting`
   `%googlekey%` is the "k" parameter from the previous step
5. You will receive the response in the form of:
   OK|Captcha_ID
   where Captcha_ID - is the id of the captcha in our system
6. After 5-10 seconds make a request to our server in the following form
   `http://2captcha.com/res.php?key=YOUR_CAPTCHA_KEY&action=get&id=Captcha_ID`
   where
   `YOUR_CAPTCHA_KEY` is your key
   `Captcha_ID` - is the CAPTCHA’s id from the previous step

   As a response you will receive:
   `OK|%response%`
   where `%response%` is the answer for passing Recaptcha.
7. In the element inspector find the line that starts with `textarea_id="g-recaptcha-response"`
8. Delete the part "display: none;"
9. On the initial page with the “I’m not a robot” CAPTCHA now there will appear an input field:
10. Enter the `%response%` that you’ve received from our server
11. Click the "Submit" button
12. You’ve passed the Recaptcha!

Refer to this link for more details: https://2captcha.com/recaptchav2_eng_instruction